# How to authorize different groups for different website in Odoo 16

Tags: odoo, odoo-16

In Odoo 16 Community version I have multiple websites. How can I assign authorizations to different groups for each website?

Comment: https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/multiple-websites-access-right-228506#:~:text=Configure%20Website%20Settings%3A%20For%20each,content%2C%20features%2C%20and%20resources.

Please provide more information for the better understanding your request.